# Pi Zero W - cgroup_cpuset not available

Tags: raspbian-stretch, pi-zero-w

Even though the contents of /boot/cmdline.txt seem right...

```
$ cat /boot/cmdline.txt
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=a435ca9f-02 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait cgroup_enable=cpuset cgroup_enable=memory cgroup_memory=1
```

I get:

```
$ cat /proc/cgroups
#subsys_name    hierarchy       num_cgroups     enabled
cpu     6       49      1
cpuacct 6       49      1
blkio   7       49      1
memory  5       78      1
devices 2       49      1
freezer 3       1       1
net_cls 4       1       1
```

How can I enable the cpuset cgroup?

I am trying Raspian Lite (Stretch) and Hypriot (1.9.0) I am open to other distros or whatever to get this working.

Hope this is supported on the Pi Zero W, ARMv6 hardware...

Comment: Could you explain what are you trying to achieve with cpusets?

Comment: Given how long ago I posted this I think at the time I was trying to make a kubernetes cluster with pi’s. This is very much a solved problem now, even though I eventually decided to just use more appropriate hardware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It block me for a long time too, and finially, I found that cpuset was enabled in raspbian jessie. you can try this one: http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian_lite/images/raspbian_lite-2017-07-05/

and then add `cgroup_enable=cpuset cgroup_enable=memory cgroup_memory=1` to boot/cmdline.txt

you can get more kernel info from here: https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-4.9.y/arch/arm/configs/bcmrpi_defconfig I have no idea why they disable it by default in newer kernel.

here is my pi zero, I enabled `CONFIG_CGROUP_PIDS=y` on kernel additionally:

```
$ uname -a
Linux edge-zero01 4.9.80+ #3 Sat Aug 15 16:20:14 CST 2020 armv6l GNU/Linux
$ cat /proc/cgroups 
#subsys_name    hierarchy   num_cgroups enabled
cpuset  2   7   1
cpu 3   7   1
cpuacct 3   7   1
blkio   4   7   1
memory  5   29  1
devices 6   54  1
freezer 7   7   1
net_cls 8   7   1
pids    9   7   1
```